# Periodically get new lines from file, possibly logrotated

Tags: logs, tail, syslog, logrotate

I'm looking for a fairly simple way (no development involved -- I could write this in Python but I'm hoping there's something already out there).

I have a log file (in my case written by rsyslogd). For analytics purposes I want to read it every 1 minute and calculate metrics for the last minute e.g. how many page hits my http server had. My 2 requirements:

1) I only want to look at the lines that were added since I last read the file. (I only need the last minute or so, and the file is too large to re-read and filter every minute).

2) Once a day the file gets logrorate'd. The first time after log rotation I want all of the lines from the previous file I haven't yet read, plus all of the lines from the new file.

I assume I'm now the only one with such requirements -- what do others do?

Comment: Just use logtail. http://linux.die.net/man/8/logtail

Comment: @Tim -- nice, but when the log gets rotated I need to print the last lines from the previous log and then all the lines in the current log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `your-filter` reads its data from stdin:

```
while your-filter; do
  sleep 60
done < file.log
```

That assumes `your-filter` just reads the data and doesn't attempt to `lseek` in it for instance.

Now, to address the log rotation issue, if on Linux (where, contrary to most other systems, `/dev/fd/n` are symlinks to the actual files), with `ksh`, `bash`, `zsh`, `dash`, `yash` (most POSIX shells except the most pedantically POSIX ones like `posh` as `-ef` is not POSIX):

```
while your-filter; do
  if [ file.log -ef /dev/stdin ]; then
    sleep 60
  else
    exec < file.log
  fi
done < file.log
```

Upon the log rotation, that would call `your-filter` twice, if you'd rather it being called once with the concatenation of the old and new:

```
while 
  if [ file.log -ef /dev/stdin ]; then
    your-filter
  else
    exec 3<&0 < file.log
    (cat <&3; cat) | your-filter &&
      exec 3<&-
  fi
do
  sleep 60
done < file.log
```

Now upon the log rotation, there may be a time when the old file.log has been renamed, but the new `file.log` not created yet, in which case the above will fail if it does the `exec < file.log` at that very moment. Then you could fix that with:

```
while 
  if [ file.log -ef /dev/stdin ] || ! command exec 3< file.log; then
    your-filter
  else
    (cat; cat <&3) | your-filter &&
      exec <&3 3<&-
  fi
do
  sleep 60
done < file.log
```

So it carries on reading the old file until the new one shows up.

`command` is needed to avoid `exec` to cause the shell to exit when it fails (as POSIX requires). It's not needed with `zsh` or `bash` when not in `sh` mode.

Now, we sleep for 60 seconds in the loop, and `your-filter` might take a few seconds to run. If it's important for `your-filter` to be run every minute on average, with `ksh`, `bash` or `zsh`, you could change it to:

```
t=$SECONDS
while 
  if [ file.log -ef /dev/stdin ] || ! command exec 3< file.log; then
    your-filter
  else
    (cat; cat <&3) | your-filter &&
      exec <&3 3<&-
  fi
do
  t=$(($t + 60))
  sleep "$((t - SECONDS))"
done < file.log
```

With `ksh93` and `zsh`, and provided your `sleep` accepts floating point arguments, you could run `typeset -F SECONDS`.

Comment: that's a fantastic answer, thank you. I wish I could upvote more than once. Not only is it a complete solution to what I asked, I also like how it is structured. Finally -- your answer made me go and read all the tldp.org chapter 20 (redirection, exec, block redirection) again, and I feel somewhat smarter now :-) Thanks.

Comment: Why not `tail -F | while sleep 60; …`?

Comment: @Gilles, because `your-filter` would block as it would never see the end-of-file.

Comment: True, you'd need a splitting pass first. Something built on `tail -F | while true; do timeout 60 cat | your-filter; done`. I get the impression that you're reimplementing `tail -F`. (Portability could be a reason for that of course.)

Comment: @Gilles -- cute. The timeout is only for `cat`, to make it stop reading it's stdin and make `your-filter` seen EOF, correct? Btw, I think this won't work if `logrotate` moves `file.log` using `mv` instead of copying it over and creating a new file. `tail` won't see that the file has moved, correct?

Comment: @Setphane -- why is the `command` part before `exec 3< file.log` needed?

Comment: @Gilles, yes that would work on a recent GNU system. There's a remote chance of `cat` being killed by `timeout` in between the time it reads data from stdin and writes it to stdout (more likely if `cat` manages to fill up its output pipe) which would make you lose data. I think you should add that as a an answer.

Comment: @NitzanShaked `tail -F` (capital `F`, option specific to GNU tail) closes the files and opens the new one by the same name if the file it's watching is renamed. Stephane: good point about the race condition.